# convert values of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv in below format

```
Used CPU    Used Memory Hard CPU    Hard Memory
    1       4Gi         50          24Gi
    0       0           0           0
    2       4Gi         4           8Gi
    2       4Gi         4           8Gi
    0       0           100m        128Mi
    51550m  39528Mi     56          47Gi
```

They are string values. In  this table 51550m means millicores which I need to convert to cores. 39528Mi is Mebibyte which I need to convert to gibibyte(or so). I want to know how I can read each value column wise and if I find `m`
(like in 51550m), convert it to core. And then convert all the values of the column into integer so that I can add them all.

I want to use pandas but I am very new to it. I know I can try `df["col_name"].astype("int")` to convert to integer but I also need to interpret millicore values to convert them.

Any help is much appreciated.

Expected Output: All values must be float. I got below from converstions

```
100 millicore = 1/10 cores
1 Mebibyte = 0.00104858 GB


  Used CPU  Used Memory Hard CPU    Hard Memory
        1       4.296       50          25.7698 
        2       4.296       4           8.592
        2       4.296       4           8.592
        0       0           .1          0.134218 
        51.550  41.448112   56          50.4659
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Do you have a mapping or a dictionary that shows the suffix characters to a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making custom functions is very easy in pandas.
Maybe you can try these :

```
# import
import pandas as pd
# reading file
df = pd.read_csv("PATH_TO_CSV_FILE")

def func_CPU(x):
    """ function for CPU related columns"""
    if x[-1] == "m":
        return float(x[:-1])/1000
    else: return x

def func_Memory(x):
    """ function for Memory related columns"""
    if x[-2:] == "Gi":
        return float(x[:-2]) * 1024 *0.00104858
    elif x[-2:] == "Mi":
        return float(x[:-2]) * 0.00104858
    else: return x



df["Used_CPU"] = df["Used_CPU"].apply(func_CPU)
df["Used_Memory"] = df["Used_Memory"].apply(func_Memory)
df["Hard_CPU"] = df["Hard_CPU"].apply(func_CPU)
df["Hard_Memory"] = df["Hard_Memory"].apply(func_Memory)
print(df)
```

Comment: I am going to try this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

**UPDATED:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file")

'''df = pd.DataFrame({'Used CPU':['1','0','2','2','0','51550m'], \
                   'Used Memory':['4Gi','0','4Gi','4Gi','0', '39528Mi'], \
                   'Hard CPU':['50','0','4','4','100m','56'], \
                   'Hard Memory':['24Gi','0','8Gi', '8Gi', '128Mi', '47Gi']})'''

units = {'m':0.001,'Mi':0.00104858,'Gi':1.0737425}
def conversion(x):
    for key in units.keys():
        if key in str(x):
            x = x.split(key)[0]
            x = (int(x)*units[key])
            return x
    return str(x)

df = df.applymap(conversion)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float64), axis=1)
print(df)
```

INPUT:

```
   Hard CPU  Hard Memory  Used CPU  Used Memory
0  50        24Gi         1         4Gi
1  0         0            0         0
2  4         8Gi          2         4Gi
3  4         8Gi          2         4Gi
4  100m      128Mi        0         0
5  56        47Gi         51550m    39528Mi
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Hard CPU  Hard Memory  Used CPU  Used Memory
0   50.0      25.76980     1.00      4.29497
1   0.0       0.000000     0.00      0.00000
2   4.0       8.589940     2.00      4.29497
3   4.0       8.589940     2.00      4.29497
4   0.1       0.134218     0.00      0.00000
5   56.0      50.465898    51.55     41.44827
```

They are in Float64. Now you can use `df['Hard Memory'] + df['Used Memory']`

Comment: Let me reduce it to few lines of code .Will be back in 1 hour.

Comment: The data is auto generated and can extend. This may not work the best

Comment: U want to change its type also ?

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal:Run this.

Comment: This one is applicable to all type of data. `df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file")` read any data it will work

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find any simple way, here is one dirty way to do it
Basically, your columns contain different string (Gi and Mi) and needs separate calculation. So, you can do something like this. Also, I am missing here calculation for Hard CPU column, but the idea is same and basically you can the same pattern for it ( Like Used CPU column) .

```
df['Used CPU'] = np.where(df['Used CPU'].str.contains('m'),
                          pd.to_numeric(df['Used CPU'].map(lambda x:str(x)[:-1])) /1000,
                          df['Used CPU'])

df['Used Memory'] = np.where(df['Used Memory'].str.contains('Mi'),
                          pd.to_numeric(df['Used Memory'].map(lambda x:str(x)[:-2])) * 0.00104858,
                          df['Used Memory'])

df['Hard Memory'] = np.where(df['Hard Memory'].str.contains('Gi'),
                          pd.to_numeric(df['Hard Memory'].map(lambda x:str(x)[:-2])) *(use math conversion here),
                          df['Hard Memory'])
```

Now, for the second column, there are Gi values too, so you can repeat the same like this

```
df['Used Memory'] = np.where(df['Used Memory'].str.contains('Gi'),
                          pd.to_numeric(df['Used Memory'].map(lambda x:str(x)[:-2])) * (do math conversion here),
                          df['Used Memory'])
```

As each items in a column needs different math conversions, if such string exists. Simple possible solution I can think is this. Sorry about that

Comment: Instead of `df['Used Memory'].map(lambda x:str(x)[:-2]))`, you can use `df['Used Memory'].str[:-2]`.

Comment: that seems even better, no need to use map

Comment: I am going to try this

Comment: also, I recommend you use `str.endswith` to be more explicit and potentially cheaper.